# PL/SQL Schema name same as Oracle Keyword

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know this sounds bizarre, but I need to execute some PL/SQL where the owner of the package has a clash with an Oracle reserve word, `IF`.

Essentially, the owner of the object is `IF`. When I use SQL Developer to execute the procedure, the generated script throws me errors since its trying to declare a cursor variable  as:

```
 variable_name IF.MYCUSTOM_TYPE
```

Currently I have no control over the schema, so I can't change anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use double quotes around the schema name, like

```
"IF".MYCUSTOM_TYPE
```

Comment: Thanks!, i knew it has to be something as simple as this.